# Connect to MongoDB in Quasar / VueJS

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, axios, mongodb-atlas, quasar-framework

I am trying to setup mongoDB in my Project (using Quasar Framework)

What I did for preparation:

- Setup MongoDB Atlas on Windows and create a user, a database and a collection
- Create a Connection String
- installed mongodb in node_modules (`npm install —-save mongodb`)

What I tested

- Using axios to get [test data in JSON format](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) (worked)
- Using axios to access the mongoDB (Didn't find a way to do it - Maybe this is not supported)
- creating a separate js file to connect to mongoDB (see below)

**Access mongoDB via js**

After I failed to access mongoDB with axios I tried to connect using this code:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient
const uri = YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING

var client;var mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { reconnectTries : 
Number.MAX_VALUE, autoReconnect : true, useNewUrlParser : true })

mongoClient.connect((err, db) => { // returns db connection
  if (err != null) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }
  client = db
})
```

Problem here is, I don't know how to implement this into my vue/quasar app. Do I have to save this as a component or can I access it directly using `<script src="app.js">`?
Is using the above code the correct way to connect to my mongoDB database or is there an easier way?

Comment: Javascript in the browser cannot directly connect to mongodb (AFAIK). You have to setup a server that's connected to mongodb. Browser js makes request to the server which makes request to mongo.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to use the MEVN approach and use Express and NodeJS for backend. I was not aware that I need a backend for handling the data.